# send html5 value to php

Tags: javascript, php, html

hi i have this code for geo location finding

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>fs</title>
    <p id="demo"></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">  function get_stored_data() {
alert(localStorage.value); }
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
   }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>The element below will receive content</p>
        <div id="div" />
        <script type="text/javascript">getLocation()</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and i want to send the values of the latitude  and longitude to php file 
that will write it in a text file

Comment: You can find everything you need here. A sidenote: `div` is not a self-closing element; it requires `</div>`

Comment: have you tried `AJAX`?

Answer (score 0):

I use $_GET or $_POST methods to pass my data to another PHP page

Answer (score 0):

You have to call ajax and send values.
This link may be helpful 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp